# Looping to number patches in Netlogo

Tags: loops, while-loop, netlogo

I am trying to simulate spatial patterns on Netlogo. I have written a code that divides the landscape into equal parts, depending on the no-of-rows and no-of-cols set by user. For example, in this case a 3 X 3 landscape consisting of 9 'camps':

[3 X 3 landscape; each smaller square is a camp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rqdb.png)

I am trying to set each camp a different plabel, numbering from 0 to 8 in this instance, in order to identify which camp this is. I have tried using loops to set this but unexpected problems are occurring.

```
to set-camp-number

  let startcol max-pxcor / no-of-cols 
  let startrow max-pycor / no-of-rows
  let t 1
  set camp-number 0
  while [ t <= no-of-cols ] [
    set a startcol * t
    ask patches with [ pxcor <= a and pxcor >= a - startcol ] [ 
      let k 1
      loop [
        if k > no-of-rows [ stop ]
        set b startrow * k
        ask patches with [ pxcor <= a and pxcor >= a - startcol and pycor <= b and pycor >= b - startrow ] [
          set plabel camp-number ]
          set camp-number camp-number + 1
          set k k + 1 ]]
   set t t + 1 ]

end
```

Instead of getting what I want (which is each camp's patches labeling themselves from 0 to 8 in this scenario), the camp-number seems to run in a loop by itself, resulting it very big values of plabel.

[My current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7E4vg.png)

I have tried other methods but this seems to be simplest to understand but I know loops can sometimes be difficult in Netlogo. I tried implementing foreach command since looping seems like such a cumbersome way to label patches (there has to be another way?) but I got stuck. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

```
globals [n-rows n-cols] ; to be set by user in your code

to setup
  ca
  set n-rows 3 
  set n-cols 3
  ask patches [set plabel category self]
end

to-report category [#patch]
  let _colstep world-width / n-cols
  let _rowstep int (world-height / n-rows)
  let _x [pxcor] of #patch - min-pxcor
  let _y [pycor] of #patch - min-pycor
  let _rownum int (_y / _rowstep)
  let _colnum int (_x / _colstep)
  report _rownum * n-cols + _colnum
end
```

Comment: Why not just say let _x pxcor - min-pxcor? Same for the y. I don't see a need to pass in a reference to itself.

Comment: This is by far a more efficient code! I grappled with the logic behind the last line a little but this makes so much more sense now! Thanks Alan!

Comment: @mattsap Yes, you could do that here.  I lean towards writing procedures without side effects, even in NetLogo.